# iPhone app user review request from code

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Can I request the user of my iPhone app to submit a review about the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Lots of apps do this. If you are going to ask for a review, make sure you include a link to the app store.

Comment: aha... I thought there is a specific class for it, but now I can see that I need to link in only a link. Thanks!

Comment: how to submit review... getting alert .. "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"